# Cannot access static website hosted on S3 bucket, from within VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, azure-static-web-app

I am looking to host a static website on AWS, using an S3 bucket.

I followed [these](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html) steps.

The site is a usual directory with subdirectories:

```
app
│   index.html   
└───scripts
│   │   things.js
│   │   stuff.js
└───images
    │   img1.png
    │   img2.jpg
```

I want to make the website accessible only to people **inside our VPC**. I attached the following type of policy to the bucket holding the site files (adding my specific bucket name and VPC id):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1415115909152",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-blahblahblah"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

I also setup a VPC endpoint, with the endpoint ID set as the value for `aws:sourceVpce` inside the bucket policy.

I setup the VPC endpoint following [these](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-private-connection-no-authentication/) steps.

But I still cannot access this site on my browser (I'm assuming that since I am accessing the AWS console with the same browser that AWS is aware I am inside the VPC).

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>blahblahblah</RequestId>
    <HostId>blahblahblah</HostId>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S3 static websites **require public access**. There is no such thing as a private S3 website in a VPC or accessible only through a VPC endpoint.

To make your S3 website work, you must set your bucket to public, or use CloudFront which also is accessible only through the internet. But at least your **bucket can be private** when you front it with CloudFront (though not the website itself).

Comment: So in order to restrict the web application to internal business users one must provide another security mechanism, such as a sign-in form backed by Amazon Cognito user pools, OAuth, or something similar.

Comment: @Cybernetic Yes, if you want to use S3. Otherwise you can host your simple website on tiny instance (t2.nano) or ecs container, to make it private only.

Comment: It looks like AWS Amplify has a good solution. Simply upload the web application files and set Access Control to "restricted", which fronts your web application with a username and password restriction.

Comment: @Cybernetic Thanks for letting me know. Sadly I don't have much exposure to Amplify.

Comment: The "Require Public Access" part is true, but the "no such thing as a private s3 website in a VPC" is incorrect. You can create an S3 Endpoint on your VPC, then use OP's bucket policy to restrict the source to only that VPC ID. You'd have to be calling it from a device that is in or routed through that VPC, so good for intranet sites using VPN/DirectConnect connections to AWS.

Comment: @MattD Thanks for comment. But the issue is about s3 website endpoints, not regular s3 endpoint. The website endpoints are only for public access from internet.

Comment: What happens if you use CloudFront for a private S3 bucket? Does it expose the private bucket contents to the public Internet?